# How to force the result order

Tags: sql, sql-server, translation

I'm writing my own translator to get more control about my translations.

Using SQL Server 2008 this is the table for the english-german dictionary:

```
CREATE TABLE engdeu 
(
    [eword] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [dword] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
  -- clipped --
  )
```

This is my text that I'm going to translate:

```
  Berlin was the first city ...
```

This is the query to translate the given english text into the german equivalent:

```
select * 
from engdeu
where eword  in ('Berlin', 'was', 'the', 'first', 'city')
```

And this is the result of the query:

```
eword   dword
city     Stadt
first    erst\e\r/es
the    der/die/das
was    wurde\n\war
Berlin Berlin
```

As you can see the order of the result is unlike the order of the origin English text.

How can I create an SQL that produces a result in the same order like that:

```
eword   dword
Berlin Berlin
was    wurde\n\war
the    der/die/das
first    erst\e\r/es
city     Stadt
```

Comment: There is no implicit order...

Comment: I wouldn't make the database handle the order. What if some word is not found at all? You have to handle it anyway, so better just get the result and handle the presentation where it belongs - in the presentation layer, not in the data layer.

Comment: Also, of course, there's no guarantee that sentences in English and German would use the same word order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use FIND_IN_SET

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(eword, 'Berlin,was,...')
```

**EDIT:**

If FIND_IN_SET is not working on Sql-server try (can't test it now sorry)

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(eword, 'Berlin,was,...')
```

Comment: I don't think [tag:sql-server] has FIND_IN_SET

Comment: Maybe CHARINDEX may be equivalent to FIND_IN_SET for sql-server (can't test it for the moment)

Comment: that's it! thank you! ORDER BY  CHARINDEX(eword, 'Berlin,was,the,first,city')

Comment: Well this is not errorproof solution... Try something like: ORDER BY CHARINDEX(eword, 'Berlin,was,the,first,city,in,as,it')

Comment: I helped for this specific need. Why would you downvote? @DarkAnavger

Comment: Because it wont work if searched word is substring of one that came before it in the sentence. So, the order for 'Berlin,is,in' wloud give You 'Berlin,in,is' in german. Based on that, I think Your solution is not good.

Comment: Sorry Theo, I am not familiar with the handling of reputation points. I can not correct my mistake becaus the SO systems insists to my made choice before 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is not task for IN clause. You have to give SQL information about order You want. One possible solution is to reach for transact SQL, and store this information in table variable, and just use JOIN and ORDER BY, like this:

```
DECLARE @vartab TABLE( 
text varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
pos varchar(30) NOT NULL 
); 
INSERT @vartab
    SELECT 1,'Berlin'
    SELECT 2,'was'
    SELECT 3,'the'
    SELECT 4,'first'
    SELECT 5,'city'
;
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    @vartab vt
LEFT JOIN engdeu ed ON (vt.text = ed.word)
ORDER BY 
    vt.pos
```

As I am unable to test it in the moment, there my be some mistakes in my code, but You should get the basic idea behind it.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188927%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is some manual from masters of good documentation.

And [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables) are some text on table variables that seems more straightfoward.

Comment: I love the net, there are so many friendly beings within! thanks a lot! ^^

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(eword VARCHAR(100),dword VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Berlin','Berlin')
                      ,('was','wurde/n/war')
                      ,('the','der/die/das')
                      ,('first','erst/e/r es')
                      ,('city','Stadt');

DECLARE @StringToTranslate VARCHAR(MAX)='Berlin was the first city in Germany';

WITH SplittedIntoWords AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ForceSortOrder 
           ,The.words.value('.','varchar(max)') AS word
    FROM (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@StringToTranslate,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXml) AS DummyTbl
    CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('x') AS The(words)
)

SELECT CASE WHEN Translation.dword IS NULL THEN '[** ' + SplittedIntoWords.word+ ' **]' ELSE Translation.dword END AS TranslatedWord 
FROM SplittedIntoWords
LEFT JOIN @tbl AS Translation ON SplittedIntoWords.word=Translation.eword
ORDER BY ForceSortOrder

/* This would concatenate the result back to a sentence
SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT ' ' + CASE WHEN Translation.dword IS NULL THEN '[** ' + SplittedIntoWords.word+ ' **]' ELSE Translation.dword END  
    FROM SplittedIntoWords
    LEFT JOIN @tbl AS Translation ON SplittedIntoWords.word=Translation.eword
    ORDER BY ForceSortOrder
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') AS OutputTranslated
*/
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution is super!

Comment: Hi @NECIP, as you are new on SO allow me one hint: It is really friendly to state this as a comment (and I really appreciate to read it), but be aware of the fact, that all professionals here giving answers are hungry for reputation points. So please: Vote all helpfull answers up an tick the best (your choice!) as accepted. This will give us the points and it will show to other users, that this question is solved, thx!

Comment: ok, thank you for the administrative crashcourse and your solution that I'll study in details. but this time the winner is Babilon becaus his/her solution fits accuratelly to my path I am on to solve my translation problems.

Comment: @NECIP, never mind, as written, this is your free choice. You know best what helps you for your specific question...

Comment: @NECIP, just for completness: Added support for words not included in the dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple T-SQL script that gives you the integral translation of any sentence separated with blanks

```
DECLARE @engdeu TABLE( 
eword varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
dword varchar(30) NOT NULL 
); 
INSERT @engdeu
    SELECT 'the','das'
    union all
    SELECT 'first','erste'
    union all
    SELECT 'city','Stadt'
    union all
    SELECT 'Berlin','Berlin'
    union all
    SELECT 'was','war'
;
/***** YOU CAN CREATE THIS PROCEDURE WITH @text(ENGLISH TEXT) AS INPUT AND HAVE @result AS AN OUTPUT *****/
DECLARE 
@text varchar(200),
@word varchar(50)='',
@result varchar(200)='',
@i int

SET @text='Berlin was the first city'

SET @text=@text+' '


WHILE LEN(isnull(@text,''))>0
BEGIN
      SET @word=SUBSTRING(@text,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@text)-1)
      SET @text=SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX(' ',@text)+1,LEN(isnull(@text,'')))
      SELECT @result=@result+' '+dword FROM @engdeu WHERE eword=@word   
END

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@result,2,LEN(@result)-1)
```

Comment: Thank's. I have additionally a second dictionary where I put in all the names, shortcuts and symbols (with there own definitions) and all the words I translated for my own purpose and look up first in this table before with a simple "case when second-table when first-table end" condition. So I'll approach with every correction to the result I was seeking for years with online translators.

Comment: Your WHILE loop is procedural thinking, but SQL needs SET BASED thinking... Loops, cursors and dynamic SQL can (almost!) ever be done better with ad-hoc SQL...

Comment: And this is the last point I would like mention: I have a third table "blacklist" that contains all the words I want to ignore to get a first raw idea of the English text.

Comment: Hi @NECIP, I'd suggest you start a new question. This is better than to ask follow up question, especially if the first one is solved already...

Comment: Hi Shnugo, my last comment was only a last completion of my idea for a translator tool. Translation in a hight quality is a hard task for a maschine. But when all the little words like "you, i, are, this, that, on, off, the..." are ignored one can recogniz the idea of the origin text rather.

Comment: @NECIP, yes, or you just use a free webservice :-)  But we should not have a private discussion below an answer given by someone else. So, Amine, excuse me please!